# Unable to get property 'done' of undefined or null reference

Tags: windows-8, winjs

Why do I get the error message **"Unable to get property 'done' of undefined or null reference"** when I run the following code?

```
new WinJS.Promise(initFunc).then(function () {
                       /* do something that returns a promise */
}).done(function () {
                       /* do something that returns a promise */
}).then(function () {
                       /* do something that returns a promise */
}).done(function () {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `done()` once in a promise chain, and that must be at the end of the chain. In the problematic code, the `done()` function is called twice in the promise chain:

```
new WinJS.Promise(initFunc).then(function () {
}).done(function () {     <====== done() is incorrectly called here--should be then()
}).then(function () {     <====== the call to then() here will throw an error
}).done(function () {             
});
```

This problem scenario can happen when your code starts off with two separate promise chains and you end up combining them together at some later point, as follows:

```
new WinJS.Promise(initFunc).then(function () {
                       /* do something that returns a promise */
}).done(function () {     <====== change this done() to a then() if you combine the two
});                               promise chains

new WinJS.Promise(initFunc).then(function () {
                       /* do something that returns a promise */
}).done(function () {
});
```

Comment: You can use .join to merge to promise chains to complete when both are complete. I think that's what your tring to get to. Just use the result of the .then, and you'll be good

Answer (score 0):

You would get the same error simply on:

```
new WinJS.Promise(initFunc).then(function () {
}).done(function () {
});
```

because your code in `then` didn't return a promise on which to call `done` on.

```
new WinJS.Promise(initFunc).then(function () {
    // Return a promise in here
    // Ex.:
    return WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000);
}).done(function () {
});
```

And to come back to your initial code, as you mentioned in your answer you shouldn't chain multiple `done` together.

Comment: You are correct. I originally had comments in the code saying exactly that, but removed them to simplify the example. I will re-add them.